# Why Split is not working in my code

Tags: c#

I am working on a windows application where I get value of a string called 'strData' from a function which has '\' in it. I want to split that string by '\' but I don't know why 'Split' function is not working.

```
 string strData= "0101-0000046C\0\0\0"; //This Value comes from a function
 string[] strTemp = strData.Split('\\');
 return strTemp[0];
```

The Value of 'strTemp[0]' is still "0101-0000046C\0\0\0". Please Help me

Comment: Are you *sure* there's \ characters in `strData`? Are you *really sure*?

Comment: If you are just interested to get the string before the \0 then use _strData = strData.Substring(0, strData.IndexOf('\0'))_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is interpreted as a non-escaped string: this means all your `\0` in your code file get resolved to the ascii-char with the value of 0 (value-zero-char).

In your case you finally have to replace the value-zero-char like this:
`strData = strData.Replace("\0", "0\\");` then it works.

**Explanation:** this replaces the value-zero-char with a number-zero-char and a backslash.

As said you either have to escape the source string to `xxx\\0` or write an `@`-sign in front of the string- declaration like this: `var x = @"xxx";` (only theoretically, second method does not work here because you said you get the value from a function). This does in both cases normally solve your issue.

Comment: Thank you for resolve the problem and understand the problem as well.

Comment: @enamur no problem :) if it helped you please don't forget to mark the answer as solved, in order to help people in the future (who have the same problem) to better identify the solution.

Answer (score 0):

code is incorrect, *backslash zero* \0 is "zero character"
If You want real backslash, use double \\

```
 string strData= "0101-0000046C\\0\\0\\0"; //This Value comes from a function
 string[] strTemp = strData.Split('\\');
 return strTemp[0];
```

Comment: yes you are right but at the time of comparing with other string variables this backslash & zeros are creating problem

Answer (score 0):

use `@` to interpret the string literally

```
string strData= @"0101-0000046C\0\0\0";
```

`\0` is only one character so add `@` before the string so that its interpreted literally